# Jquery appends HTML strangely into a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
$("#samplediv").html("<div>");  
$("#samplediv").append("<b>Test text</b>");
$("#samplediv").append("</div>");
```

I require the following output:

```
<div><b>Test text</b></div>
```

However, the output is:

```
<div></div><b>Test text</b>
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the browser doing it, not jquery. Most browsers are going to fix faultly HTML as best they can. If you add only part of a Div, it will fix it by adding the rest.

Here is some info though... 
Dom queries are costly in all JS, even more so in jQuery. In yours, you are doing three. You can reduce that to one, by doing the following code:

```
var html = "<div>";
html+="<b>Test text</b>";
html+="</div>";
$("#samplediv").html(html);
```

If you build your html separate, and then do your append, you will be able to do what you want. This is the recommended way of dealing with DOM manipulation. It is way more performent.

Comment: @aaronfrost Thanks for fixing my typos and mistakes, had to reject the edit since I had done changes myself but applied your corrections to another update :)

Answer (score 3):

jQuery does not append *strings* of HTML, but DOM *elements* (created by parsing the input HTML).

Thus, the above does as it should:

```
$("#samplediv").html("<div>"); // Create <div /> element
$("#samplediv").append("<b>Test text</b>"); // Append <b>...</b> _after_ <div />
$("#samplediv").append("</div>"); // Discard, invalid element.
```

The above answers the "why" part of your question. Other answers will guide you in the direction of "how" to achieve the desired result.

Comment: The problem is that the first $().html() is only adding part of a div (leaving off the closing tag). The browser is fixing it and adding the closing tag for him. So... APPEND doesn't add Strings, but .html() does add the exact string you pass it and then the browser tries to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You are assuming that [`.append`](http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fappend%2F&ei=jIV5TqrvF4WK4gSA8eHiDw&usg=AFQjCNHOUufNEqoLDGnYJCokTxkU1HnY3w) merely add your string to the DOM, which is a faulty assumption. `.append` is using the browsers JavaScript API (usually the innerHTML method) to inject your code, and will (should) add any missing closing tags and discard invalid code.

When you do `.append("<div>")`, it will actually add `<div></div>` to the DOM which is why you're getting that result.

To get the result you want, you either want to use concatenated strings or create a jQuery object which you can play with.

#### Method #1: Concatenated strings

```
var html = "<div>";
html += "<b>Test text</b>";
html += "</div>";
$("#samplediv").html(html);
```

#### Method #2: jQuery object

```
var myDiv = $("<div></div>");
myDiv.append("<b>Test text</b>");
$("#samplediv").html(myDiv);
```

*Note: Working with strings instead of jQuery objects is alot faster, so if you don't need to hook up any events or need the flexibility it's strongly recommended to use the first method.*

Manipulating the DOM is slow and cumbersome, which is why I didn't provide a method that appends part after part (like in your example). It's a good practice to try and minimize the amount of manipulation you do to the DOM.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Comment: @Nick, you're welcome! I always try to elaborate on my answers to try and cover more then the problem itself and to shed some light on both the good and bad practices. I want to applaud aaronfrost for his answer and his urge to correct my noobish misspells and mistakes :D

Answer (score 1):

When you append the first string, a well-formed div is appended, which means both opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can try based on your method.

```
$("#samplediv").html("<div></div>"); 
$("#samplediv div").append("<b>Test text</b>");
```

However there are many other methods to append the div element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#samplediv").html('<div></div>');   
$("#samplediv div").append("<b>Test text</b>");
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Append doesn't work like that. This will...

```
var myDiv = $('<div></div>');
myDiv.append("<b>Test text</b>");
$("#samplediv").append(myDiv);
```

Comment: Well... it was a significant typo, and you told someone to use your code. The Tiger that should "take it easy" is you. Take it easy on clicking the Post Your Answer button. Make sure the code compiles/runs first.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code now, and yet your downvote remains...I am getting sick of flagging your comments, what is your objective with this one? You pointed out the mistake, I fixed it. What more do you want...

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you're after is such thing:

```
$("#samplediv").html($("<div>").html("<b>Test text</b>"));
```

This logic still separates things like in your original code but put it all inside the same `<div>`.